# How to find sequences of valid tuples

Tags: algorithm, graph, tuples, sequence

I have `n` tuples `(x_i, y_i, z_i)`. I want to find the minimum number of sequences such that each tuple in the sequence `(x_i, y_i, z_i)` and `(x_j, y_j, z_j)` is such that `x_i >= x_j`, `y_i >= y_j`, and `z_i >= z_j`. All `n` tuples must be assigned to one and only one sequence.

For example, if I had three tuples with values `(1, 2, 3), (2, 2, 3), and (1, 1, 7)`, the minimum number of valid sequences is 2, which are `(2, 2, 3) and (1, 2, 3)` and `(1, 1, 7)` by itself.

I want to find an algorithm that can return this minimum number in `O(n^3)` time. I was considering checking each tuple against each other tuple but there must be a more efficient way to solve this. Any pointers would be appreciated!

Comment: What does "minimum number of sequences" mean? Does each tuple in the set of `n` tuples have to be used at least once in any of the sequences? Or exactly once? Please elaborate.

Comment: @cSharp all ``n`` tuples must be assigned to one and only one sequence. I would prefer to put as many tuples into one sequence as possible, which is why I'm looking for the minimum number of sequences

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Please edit your question to include that information!

Comment: The second sentence is missing a few words. Do you mean that each sequence should be totally ordered?

Comment: @kcsquared i just reworded it hopefully it's clearer now

Comment: It's still not completely clear. Do you mean that each sequence is a [total order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_order)? Also, can you share the algorithm you were considering that compares each tuple against every other one? That seems like it already would meet the O(n^3) time bound

Comment: Whenever I hear `n^3` I think dynamic programming.

Comment: @kcsquared so for example, if I have a sequence of size 4, with 4 tuples. From the first tuple to the last tuple, x_i >= x_j, y_i >= y_j, and z_i >= z_j for each of the tuples. After considering it some more, I think I would have to check each pair of tuples against each other which would be O(n^2). After this, maybe draw edges between each pair and do a topological sort? But I'm not entirely sure how that would fit the runtime bound.